# Timing/Clocks in the Linux Kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am writing a device driver and want to benchmark a few pieces of code to get a feel for where I could be experiencing some bottlenecks. As a result, I want to time a few segments of code.

In userspace, I'm used to using `clock_gettime()` with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`. Looking at the kernel sources (note that I am running kernel 4.4, but will be upgrading eventually), it appears I have a few choices:

- `getnstimeofday()`
- `getrawmonotonic()`
- `get_monotonic_coarse()`
- `getboottime()`

For convenience, I have written a function (see below) to get me the current time. I am currently using `getrawmonotonic()` because I figured this is what I wanted. My function returns the current time as a `ktime_t`, so then I can use `ktime_sub()` to get the elapsed time between two times.

```
static ktime_t get_time_now(void) {
   struct timespec time_now;
   getrawmonotonic(&time_now);
   return timespec_to_ktime(time_now);
}
```

Given the available high resolution clocking functions (jiffies won't work for me), what is the best function for my given application? More generally, I'm interested in any/all documentation about these functions and the underlying clocks. Primarily, I am curious if the clocks are affected by any timing adjustments and what their epochs are.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you comparing measurements you're making in the kernel directly with measurements you've made in userspace? I'm wondering about your choice to use `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` as the timebase in the kernel, since you chose to use `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` in userspace. If you're looking for an analogous and non-coarse function in the kernel which returns `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` (and not `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW`) time, look at `ktime_get_ts()`.

It's possible you could also be using raw kernel ticks to be measuring what you're trying to measure (rather than jiffies, which represent multiple kernel ticks), but I do not know how to do that off the top of my head.

In general if you're trying to find documentation about Linux timekeeping, you can take a look at `Documentation/timers/timekeeping.txt`. Usually when I try to figure out kernel timekeeping I also unfortunately just spend a lot of time reading through the kernel source in `time/` (`time/timekeeping.c` is where most of the functions you're thinking of using right now live... it's not super well-commented, but you can probably wrap your head around it with a little bit of time). And if you're feeling altruistic after learning, remember that updating documentation is a good way to contribute to the kernel :)

To your question at the end about how clocks are affected by timing adjustments and what epochs are used:

`CLOCK_REALTIME` always starts at Jan 01, 1970 at midnight (colloquially known as the Unix Epoch) if there are no RTC's present or if it hasn't already been set by an application in userspace (or I guess a kernel module if you want to be weird). Usually the userspace application which sets this is the ntp daemon, `ntpd` or `chrony` or similar. Its value represents the number of seconds passed since 1970.

`CLOCK_MONTONIC` represents the number of seconds passed since the device was booted up, and if the device is suspended at a `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` value of `x`, when it's resumed, it resumes with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` set to `x` as well. It's not supported on ancient kernels.

`CLOCK_BOOTTIME` is like `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`, but has time added to it across suspend/resume -- so if you suspend at a `CLOCK_BOOTTIME` value of `x`, for 5 seconds, you'll come back with a `CLOCK_BOOTTIME` value of `x+5`. It's not supported on old kernels (its support came about after `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`).

Fully-fleshed NTP daemons (not SNTP daemons -- that's a more lightweight and less accuracy-creating protocol) set the system clock, or `CLOCK_REALTIME`, using `settimeofday()` for large adjustments ("steps" or "jumps") -- these immediately affect the total value of `CLOCK_REALTIME`, and using `adjtime()` for smaller adjustments ("slewing" or "skewing") -- these affect the rate at which `CLOCK_REALTIME` moves forward per CPU clock cycle. I think for some architectures you can actually tune the CPU clock cycle through some means or other, and the kernel implements `adjtime()` this way if possible, but don't quote me on that. From both the bulk of the kernel's perspective and userspace's perspective, it doesn't actually matter.

`CLOCK_MONOTONIC`, `CLOCK_BOOTTIME`, and all other friends slew at the same rate as `CLOCK_REALTIME`, which is actually fairly convenient in most situations. They're not affected by steps in `CLOCK_REALTIME`, only by slews.

`CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW`, `CLOCK_BOOTTIME_RAW`, and friends do NOT slew at the same rate as `CLOCK_REALTIME`, `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`, and `CLOCK_BOOTIME`. I guess this is useful sometimes.

Linux provides some process/thread-specific clocks to userspace (`CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID`, `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID`), which I know nothing about. I do not know if they're easily accessible in the kernel.

Comment: If you want the time as a `ktime_t` (as the question implied), then it would be even more useful to call `ktime_get` (for monotonic), `ktime_get_raw()` for raw-monotonic, etc.

Comment: There's no clock named `CLOCK_BOOTTIME_RAW`